# Display element in a grid and conditionally add to redux or remove if not selected

Tags: array, react.js, jsx, scope

I have some logic on my JSX for an element in a grid, if element is selected, then add to redux, if element is not selected then remove from redux...

is working ok, but I sense a bad smell...

```
<GridSelector
          items={items}
          onChange={(categoryId, isSelected) => {
            favorites[categoryId] = isSelected;
            const favsArraya = Object.values(onboarding.favoriteCategories);
            let index;

            if(isSelected){
              if (favsArraya.indexOf(categoryId) === -1){
                //doesnt exist, add it
                 favsArraya.push(categoryId)
              }
            }else{
              if (favsArraya.indexOf(categoryId) !== -1){
                // exists, delete it
                index = favsArraya.indexOf(categoryId);
                favsArraya.splice(index, 1);
              }
            }

            dispatchData({ [DATA_KEY.FAVORITE_CATEGORIES]: favsArraya})

          }}
        />
```

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/254685/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's way too much going on here for an inline function. Let's seperate that out. Also, the splicing can be replaced with the more expressive filter.

```
const addIfMissing = (array, item) =>
    array.includes(item) ? array : array.concat([item]);

const without = (array, exclude) =>
    array.filter(x=> x!==exclude);

const onGridSelectorChange = (categoryId, isSelected) => {
    favorites[categoryId] = isSelected;
    const categoryIds = Object.values(onboarding.favoriteCategories);
    const newCategoryIds = isSelected ?
        addIfMissing(categoryIds,categoryId) :
        without(categoryIds,categoryId);

    dispatchData({ [DATA_KEY.FAVORITE_CATEGORIES]: newCategoryIds})

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, what is the name of that kind of inline function writing? 
functional programming? reactive programming?

Comment: the inline function is a JS arrow function. It's useful for functional programming, but does not necessarily imply "pure" functional code

Answer (score 2):

Why is `index` declared at the top of the `onChange` handler? It is only used within the `else` block once. Thus it could be declared there using `const`.

```
const index = favsArraya.indexOf(categoryId);
favsArraya.splice(index, 1);
```

Not only does this eliminate an extra empty declaration, using `const` is a good habit because it can help avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).

And that variable can be eliminated since it is only used once:

```
favsArraya.splice(favsArraya.indexOf(categoryId), 1);
```

Comment: I don't believe the conditionals can be combined. Consider the case where `isSelected=false` and `categoryId` does not exist within `favsArraya`

Comment: Okay that makes sense- thanks for clarifying.